# No daemon process found when trying to restart Monit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, monit

Status not available -- the monit daemon is not running.  When I use command `monit quit` I get `No daemon process found`.  This if for a Rails application running on AWS.

Stack:

- AWS - Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
- Architecture - x86_64
- nginx/1.4.6
- Rails 4.1.12
- Unicorn-4.9.0
- mysql2-0.3.18

In Root:

```
set pidfile /tmp/monit.pid
set idfile /tmp/.monit.id
set statefile /tmp/.monit.state
set logfile /var/log/monit.log

set mailserver smtp.sendgrid.net
  port <Sendgrid Port>
  username <Sendgrid Username>
  password <Our Sendgrid Account Password>
  with timeout 30 seconds
  set mail-format {from: <Our Sendgrid Account>}
  set alert <Dev Email>
  set alert <Dev Email>

set httpd port <Our Monit Port>
 use address <Our IP Address>
 allow <Our NAT IP Address>
 allow admin:<Monit Password>

check process crond with pidfile /var/run/crond.pid
 start "/etc/init.d/cron start"
 stop "/etc/init.d/cron stop"
 group system

check process nginx with pidfile /run/nginx.pid
 start "/etc/init.d/nginx start"
 stop "/etc/init.d/nginx stop"
 group system

 check device rootfs with path /
if SPACE usage > 80% then alert

check device ebs_storage with path /mnt/ebs_storage
  if SPACE usage > 80% then alert

include /var/www/*/current/config/monit.conf
```

In Deploy monit.conf:

```
check process <Our App>_unicorn with pidfile /var/www/<Our App>/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`
start "/etc/init.d/<Our App>_unicorn start"`
stop  "/etc/init.d/<Our App>_unicorn stop"`
group <Our App>`
check process <Our App>_delayed_job with pidfile /var/www/<Our App>/current/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid`
start program = "/etc/init.d/<Our App>_delayed_job start"`
stop program = "/etc/init.d/<Our App>_delayed_job stop"`
 if mem is greater than 300.0 MB for 1 cycles then restart`
 if cpu is greater than 50% for 2 cycles then alert`
 if cpu is greater than 80% for 3 cycles then restart`
group <Our App>
```

The original developer set up Monit directly from the binary and didn't use 'apt' to install it.  It appears in both the root and deploy user in `/usr/local/bin/monit`.  The Rails app runs fine as did Monit until about a week ago.  Now it doesn't restart processes or alert us.  I realize this is because the daemon isn't running, but can't get it to restart. `Monit -t` in both root and deploy return `Control file syntax ok`.

First, I didn't set this up, nor have I set up monit before, so I'm a bit lost.  Monit was installed from a binary into the `/usr/local/bin/monit` by the previous developer and not using apt.  The Rails app runs fine, but due to some quirks in its requirements there are things that are out of our control that can cause the app to crash.  Monit was doing a great job of restarting everything.  Then suddenly, it stopped working.  Some things were being changed in our VPC at the time, so it could be that.  What I don't understand is why I can't get the daemon to restart no matter what I do.  When I do `sudo monit -t` while in deploy or just `monit -t` in root, I get Control file syntax OK.  Monitor appears to be in the right place.

I've never set up Monit so I'm a little lost.  I can't seem to get it to restart and cannot figure out if its a configuration issue or something else.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Someone commented and said I might have duplicate copies of monit in my path.  They comment disappeared.  They told me to type:

`sudo /usr/local/bin/monit -t`

I did this in deploy and root and it returned **Control file syntax OK**.  Monit was installed directly from binary not using apt, so they told me to use the command:

`type -path monic`

Which returned /usr/local/bin/monit in both root and deploy.  Sorry to the person who was helping.  I don't know if I deleted your comment or what, but thanks for your help so far.